# Views Filters: find nodes that have more than one term in taxonomy vocabulary

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

How can I set a filter to find nodes that have **more than one term** in a particular taxonomy vocabulary?

*Note: The vocabulary allow unlimited values and is required field. So, nodes can have 1-∞ terms.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to list down only those nodes of a specific content type that has more than one taxonomy term, I did the following and could only see nodes with more than one taxonomy term:

1. Create content type with taxonomy term field
2. Create views with following filter criterias

   A. Published=Yes

   B. Content Type={Your Content type}

   C. taxonomy term field:delta (= 1)

For "C" I have clicked on Add filter criteria, then searched for the (content type's) field that contains taxonomy term and selected the one that has :delta (i.e. my field name is field_taxonomy_term and I choose field_taxonomy_term:delta), Once you selected the delta of your taxonomy term field then choose the operator as ***is equal to*** and provide the value as ***1*** and save.

If a content type has exactly one taxonomy term then the delta field will never have index 1 but, will always have index 0. If a node has more than one taxonomy term (i.e. 2) then there is index 1 (Index 1 is always present for content types with more than one taxonomy term), that is why the filtering works.

See the screenshots for more info:

The page is configured to show only nodes with more than one taxonomy temr
[image: Page configured to show nodes with more than one taxonomy term]

The following attachment is configured to show all nodes (it is then attached to the page)
[image]

The result of the above page and attachment is as follow 
[image]

In case you are interested in the view, here is the export code:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'viewfornodewithtaxonomy';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'ViewForNodeWithTaxonomy';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Attachment display all nodes with any taxonomy terms';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '20';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['id'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['quantity'] = '9';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: taxonomy terms */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_taxonomy_terms']['id'] = 'field_taxonomy_terms';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_taxonomy_terms']['table'] = 'field_data_field_taxonomy_terms';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_taxonomy_terms']['field'] = 'field_taxonomy_terms';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_taxonomy_terms']['delta_offset'] = '0';
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'nodewithtaxonomy' => 'nodewithtaxonomy',
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['group'] = 1;
/* Filter criterion: Content: taxonomy terms (field_taxonomy_terms:delta) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['delta']['id'] = 'delta';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['delta']['table'] = 'field_data_field_taxonomy_terms';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['delta']['field'] = 'delta';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['delta']['value']['value'] = '1';

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['title'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'page display node with at least one taxonomy term';
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'viewfornodewithtaxonomy';

/* Display: Attachment */
$handler = $view->new_display('attachment', 'Attachment', 'attachment_1');
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filter_groups'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filters'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'nodewithtaxonomy' => 'nodewithtaxonomy',
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['displays'] = array(
  'page' => 'page',
  'default' => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['attachment_position'] = 'after';
```

Don't forget to mark your question as resolved if the answer helped you.

Comment: Nice one! I didn't know what exactly meant the delta thing but now I know it's for multiple values fields. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for the right words I missed in my answer, correct it is for fields with multiple values.